# Dynamically remove a layer from a layer-list

Tags: android, android-drawable, layer-list

I would like to remove/hide a layer in a layer-list during runtime. How do I do this?

I built a solution that works, but it feels a bit hackish.

I replace the desired layer with a transparent image:

```
LayerDrawable layerDrawable = (LayerDrawable) res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_layer);
Drawable digit = res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_number_empty);
layerDrawable.setDrawableByLayerId(R.id.layer_digit, digit);
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: I have never been in that situatio, but reading LayerDrawable documentation ``https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/LayerDrawable.html`` you could use some methods like ``setAlpha()``, ``setOpacity()`` or ``setVisible()``

Comment: @Gonzalo, That's for the `LayerList` and not the individual layers.

Answer (score 0):

How about `layerDrawable.findDrawableByLayerId(R.id.layer_digit).setAlpha(0)`?